# loop through all possible combination of 8 bytes

Tags: python

I want to do something like this:

```
for i in range('\xff'*8):
  hash = b'challenge' + i
  inp = hashlib.sha256(hash).digest()
```

I don't know how i can get all the possible combinations of 8 bytes with bitwise operations.

Comment: itertools.combinations ?

Comment: can i do it with bitwise operations? i prefer without library

Comment: There are 1.8e19 8byte values so your program will take rather long

Comment: it's okay. it's supposed to be brute force so

Comment: I want to find a hash that begins with 26 zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, but using struct would be preferred, I've also added the zero check (increase 2 to 26...):

```py
start = b'\0' * 2
import hashlib
for i in range(256 ** 8):
    byte = b'challenge' + bytes.fromhex("%016x" % i)
    inp = hashlib.sha256(byte).digest()
    if inp.startswith(start):
        print(byte, inp)
        break
```

Output:

```
b'challenge\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00*\xde' b'\x00\x00\x9a\x84H\xbc\x07\xd7\xdc\x07#\xb8\x08A\xb1&\xdcD\xb0 \x84\\9y#\xc9\xcf\xaa\xff\xb7\xbf\x9a'
...
```

I mean you're already using hashlib, so you could as well use another standard library:

```py
start = b'\0' * 2
import hashlib, struct
for i in range(256 ** 8):
    byte = b'challenge' + struct.pack(">Q", i)
    inp = hashlib.sha256(byte).digest()
    if inp.startswith(start):
        print(byte, inp)
        break
```

Comment: I would just use `"Q"` rather than `"<Q"`. 2 possible cases: you are already on a LE machine (most people nowadays), in which case, both are identical and it doesn't matter. Or you are not, and then forcing `"<"`, adds about 11-12% of time to pack. And it is not like you really care that it is LE (on the contrary: you first version iterate in the order of `>Q`, so apparently you don't really want `<Q`).  Sure, you can object that 11-12% of time in struct is negligible before the time spent in hashlib afterward, but even then: why bother adding the `<`?

Comment: what does `%016x` mean?

Comment: Oh, in the meantime you changed to `>Q`. So, maybe you care after all :D

Comment: Convert number to hex and add leading zeroes up to 16.

Comment: @chrslg, yeah I do care, I just copied it from another program without checking. I've now added a faster loop for big endian machines.

Comment: shouldn't it be 255? because the largest number 1 byte can present?

Comment: sorry i don't get it. the biggest number is `b'\xff'*8` which is 255*8... why it's 256

Comment: Oh, sorry, that's because you're working with 8 bytes. For that the biggest number is not 255 **8, but 256 ** 8 - 1 exactly what a range does.

Comment: You faster version is not really need: on BE machine, `>Q` is as fast as `Q`. It is when you force the machine to iterates "unnatural" (from its point of view) that it is slower. That is saying `>Q` on LE machine. But since you care of the iteration order, then you need it. In other words, if you care of the order, no need to try to avoid `>` (like I said before, but seen from the other point of view: either it changes the order, and then you need it; or it doesn't, and then it changes nothing to timing neither).

Comment: Ah, OK then I'll get rid off, thanks for your time.

Comment: My previous comment was just because I thought it doesn't really matter whether we iterate `0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1`, `0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2`, ... `255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255`, or we iterate `1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0`, `2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0`, ..., `255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255`. As long as it is brute force... (and more importantly I thought you were thinking so as well). But there are arguments in favor of caring. For example if we want then to batch run this brute force on many machines, some being LE, other being BE. In which case it is better to, as you did, specify order.